# mock HTTP response with promises and return dummy data

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I am calling an API service which returns a promise from a factory.

Here is a part of my factory.

```
     factories.factory('OnBoardingFactory', ['$http',

        function ($http) {

          var dataFactory = {};

          dataFactory.get = function (url) {
            return $http.get('http://localhost/api/onboarding/' + url)
          };

          return dataFactory
        }

     ]);
```

And here is where its called from the controller:

```
OnBoardingFactory.get('login?username=test&password=password')
   .then(function(response){
      $scope.response = response.status;
   })
```

This returns data in the controller absolutely fine. However I have difficulties when I come to test it. Here is my test script:

```
var scope, FakeOnBoardingFactory, controller, q, deferred;

beforeEach(module('app.module'));

beforeEach(function () {
  FakeOnBoardingFactory = {
    get: function () {
      deferred = q.defer();
      // Place the fake return object here
      deferred.resolve({ response: {status: 200}});
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  spyOn(FakeOnBoardingFactory, 'get').and.callThrough();
});

beforeEach(inject(function ($q, $rootScope, $controller, $injector ) {

  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  q = $q;

  controller = $controller(OnBoardingCtrl, {
    $scope: scope,
    OnBoardingFactory: FakeOnBoardingFactory
  })

}));

it('Should call the form and return 200', function () {

  // Execute form
  scope.loginCredentials({$valid: true});

  scope.$apply();

  // Ensure script is called (which passes fine)
  expect(FakeOnBoardingFactory.get).toHaveBeenCalled();

  scope.$apply();

  // BREAKS HERE
  expect(scope.status).toBe(200);

})
```

When `expect(FakeOnBoardingFactory.get).toHaveBeenCalled();` is called, this passes fine. However then I run `expect(scope.status).toBe(200)`, it breaks "Expected undefined to be 200".

This would indicate that my FakeOnBoardingFactory isn't returning any data. But I can't seem to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the change to support multiple body assertions that has caused this bug. 
The workaround for now is to either don't use expect and do your assertion in the end function callback.
 So instead of .expect(200) it would be.

```
end(function(err,res) { res.status.should.equal(200) },
```

or if you do use expect.. you need to make sure you specify a body as well as just a status..

```
it('should assert status only 1', function(done){ 
var app = express(); 
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
 res.send(201, { name: 'tobi' }); }); request(app) .get('/user')
 .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
 .expect('Content-Length', '20')
 .expect(201)
 .end(function(err, res){
 if (err) throw err; 
}); 
})
```